# Virtualbox running vagrant has no storage device attached

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'm running VirtualBox 4.3.6r91406 and Vagrant 1.4.3. The host OS is Mavericks. Whenever I try to boot the VM, it throws the following error.

```
ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) 
aIID={480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} 
aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={
No storage device attached to device slot 1 on port 0 of 
controller 'IDE Controller'}, preserve=false
```

The machine was running fine an hour ago, so I'm not sure why this is suddenly freaking 
out.

I've updated Vagrant and Virtual box.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled them both.  But I still don't understand why I'm getting this error or how to fix it.

What do I have to do to stop this error from being thrown?

Comment: Hey, Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: I honestly can't remember...This happened about 4 years ago.

Comment: I'm experiencing this error. No solution?

Answer (score -4):

connect virtual disk to Slot1 on port 0 with IID